# Exiv2 with makefile

Tags: linux, makefile, g++, exiv2

I need to include my Exiv2 extension in my project using Makefile.
I succeeded to run it directly through terminal with:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lexiv2
```

My original Makefile (it works) important part:

```
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -fpic -o
LINKER_FLAGS        =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui \
                        -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d \
                        -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect \
```

Now I have to run a program that uses Exiv2 with a Makefile.
Now I'm trying to customize the Makefile, tried

```
COMPILER_FLAGS      =   -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -fpic -o
LINKER_FLAGS        =   -shared
LINKER_DEPENDENCIES =   -lphpcpp -lopencv_core -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui \
                        -lopencv_ml -lopencv_video -lopencv_features2d \
                        -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_objdetect \
                        -lexiv2 \
```

Doesn't work, output of make is:

```
[root@localhost psdk4]# make
g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -fpic -o metacopy.o metacopy.cpp
metacopy.cpp: In member function ‘int Params::copyMetadata(int, char**)’:
metacopy.cpp:50:9: error: ‘AutoPtr’ is not a member of ‘Exiv2::BasicIo’
         Exiv2::BasicIo::AutoPtr fileIo(new Exiv2::FileIo(params.read_));
         ^
metacopy.cpp:50:33: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘fileIo’
         Exiv2::BasicIo::AutoPtr fileIo(new Exiv2::FileIo(params.read_));

...
```

It means that it doesn't find the Exiv2 methods, how to customize my Makefile?

Comment: I don't see how makefile has anything to do with it. If the compiler cannot find something, then it is not there, and makefile cannot help --- unless it is somehow conditionally compiled, but we have no information about it and can say nothing without seeing the code.

Comment: I was saying that I succeeded compiling a program that uses Exiv2 with:
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -lexiv2

so it can be used properly, now my Makefile needs to include flags and dependencies in a correct way

Comment: "a program that uses Exiv2" doesn't tell me much. In what way does it use Exiv2? Does it use Exiv2::BasicIo::AutoPtr?

Comment: Just because a test program works doesn't mean different code will work.  If you cut and paste make's compile line to your shell prompt and run it and you _don't_ see those errors, then we can conclude the problem is in the makefile somewhere.  If you DO so those errors (which I'm sure you will) then the problem is either in your code (maybe you forgot an #include) or else the arguments you're passing to the compiler are still not right.  Once you get it to compile from the command line you can fix your makefile.

Comment: BTW as a general rule it's a bad idea to be doing development and running make as the root user on your system.

Answer (score 1):

`AutoPtr` (which was an alias to `std::auto_ptr`) was removed from Exiv2 in December 2018. Note that `std::auto_ptr` itself was deprecated from C++ in 2011 and removed altogether in 2017.

[Relevant Diff on Github](https://github.com/Exiv2/exiv2/commit/427bbad060f044f5857416af6633f3595af198ba#diff-c21870c8fbe00d499fe5ba71f650ff55)

Your code that depends on `AutoPtr` is too old. You might be able to update it by replacing `AutoPtr` with `UniquePtr`. You will have to find all places where the former `auto_ptr` was copied (assigned, passed to a function and the like) and insert a call to [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/move) around the source of the copy. The compiler will complain about a deleted function (copy constructor or copy assignment), so it's easy to fix these places one by one. For example:

```
 AutoPtr some_variable = ...;
 ...
 some_function(some_variable);
```

needs to become

```
 UniquePtr some_variable = ...;
 ...
 some_function(std::move(some_variable));
```

Comment: I've got a new error:
make
g++ -Wall -c -O2 -std=c++11 -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -fpic -o metacopy.o metacopy.cpp
metacopy.cpp: In member function ‘int Params::copyMetadata(int, char**)’:
metacopy.cpp:55:74: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = Exiv2::BasicIo; _Dp = std::default_delete<Exiv2::BasicIo>]’
         Exiv2::Image::UniquePtr readImg = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(memIo);

Comment: In file included from /usr/include/c++/4.8.2/memory:81:0,
                 from /usr/local/include/exiv2/value.hpp:40,
                 from /usr/local/include/exiv2/metadatum.hpp:37,
                 from /usr/local/include/exiv2/datasets.hpp:32,
                 from /usr/local/include/exiv2/exiv2.hpp:32,
                 from metacopy.cpp:1:
/usr/include/c++/4.8.2/bits/unique_ptr.h:273:7: error: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

Comment: /usr/local/include/exiv2/image.hpp:444:33: error:   initializing argument 1 of ‘static Exiv2::Image::UniquePtr Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(Exiv2::BasicIo::UniquePtr)’
         static Image::UniquePtr open(BasicIo::UniquePtr io);
                                 ^
make: *** [metacopy.o] Error 1

Comment: @TomerBarak So you cannot update it in such a simple way, you may have to insert `std::move` where the former auto_ptr was copied. (auto_ptr had weird copy semantics; unique_ptr cannot be copied at all, it must be moved) Will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

This worked:

```
readImg = Exiv2::ImageFactory::open(std::move(memIo));
```